# ASP.NET Display SVN Revision Number

Tags: asp.net, svn

I see in the Stack Overflow footer that the SVN Revision number is displayed. Is this automated and if so, how does one implement it in ASP.NET?

*(Solutions in other languages are acceptable)*

Comment: If you're using ASP.Net MVC, I've written an [easy to follow 3-step guide on how to automatically get and display the latest SVN revision](http://www.fatlemon.co.uk/2008/12/automatic-svn-revision-numbering-in-aspnet-mvc/ "Automatic SVN revision numbering in ASP.Net MVC - www.fatlemon.co.uk") :o)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the file has s`vn:keywords "Rev Id"` and then put `$Rev$` somewhere in there.

See [this question and the answers to it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/163/10221765).

Answer (score 0):

in our continuous integration setup we use `SVNRevisionLabeller` and pass the variables from this to MSBuild to use when creating the compiled website dll. It's then available to .NET using `GetCurrentAssembly()` in the final build.

Answer (score 0):

In my rails app I have a secret action which literally does this:

```
render :text => `svn info #{RAILS_ROOT}`
```

This is the equivalent of `Process.Start( "svn info..." )` if you're only familiar with `.NET`)

If I'm wondering if the guy who manages the servers has updated the site recently, I can hit this URL, and have a look.