# How to overwrite an image with the same name on Firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem with my android app. When I try to overwrite an image on firebase storage, even if I delete the old image and put a new one, it always takes me to the old one. I have checked on the storage from the console and there is only the new image. I want to put images with the same name into Storage to have an easy access from my application.

```
StorageReference stRef = storageRef.child("images/" + uuid);
stRef.delete();
stRef.putFile(imageUri);
```

Answer (score 2):

If the new image is on Firestore Storage, then Firebase Storage will return that image when any new clients request it. There is no way for it to return the old data, once you've uploaded the new image.

This means that it's more likely that a client is using the cached data of the old image. It's hard to say why that is with the information you shared, but you'll want to look in that direction: how are you retrieving the data, and where could it be caching the results from the previous call?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. It was due to the cache.
After overwriting, the old image even showed up in multiple devices (in the same network)

Each you overwrite the images, you would need to invalidate the cache for those.

To invalidate the cache you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552969/can-i-clear-a-specific-url-in-the-browsers-cache-using-post-or-otherwise)