# Does the 'PURGE' method in HTTP only removes the object from cache memory?

Tags: api, http, testing, postman, purge

I have searched for purge method but didn't found anything precise.

> A purge is what happens when you pick out an object from the cache and
> discard it along with its variants. Usually a purge is invoked through
> HTTP with the method PURGE. An HTTP purge is similar to an HTTP GET
> request, except that the method is PURGE.

This is what I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, you can send the PURGE method to remove a resource from the cache. This is a example to illustrate this:

GET /article/1234 HTTP/1.1

- The resource is not cached yet
- Send request to the API
- Store response in cache and return

GET /article/1234 HTTP/1.1

- The resource is cached
- Return response from cache

PURGE /article/1234 HTTP/1.1

- API sends PURGE method to the cache
- The resources is removed from the cache

GET /article/1234 HTTP/1.1

- The resource is not cached yet
- Send request to the API
- Store response in cache and return

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you show some context; this method is for [Varnish, a caching server](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/3.0/tutorial/purging.html).

So yes, purging a cache entry only purges the cache entry, the underlying entity (wherever it comes from) is untouched.