# How to auto increment the version (eg. “1.0.*”) of a .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, versioning

In the old .NET framework, you could set the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]` and the compiler would auto-increment the version.

With .NET core, I've tried all sorts of things, but I can't get it to auto-increment.

- I've added `<Deterministic>False</Deterministic>` and `<AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>` to the .csproj per [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43019832/auto-versioning-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core).  The code compiles but the version stays the same
- I've tried the same thing but with `<Version>1.0.*</Version>` tag as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58433665/how-to-specify-the-assembly-version-for-a-net-core-project).  This actually set the product version to 1.0.* (with the asterisk).
- I've set the Assembly Version in the Property Properties/Package page.  Doesn't seem to do anything either.

None of it seems to work. Am I missing something simple? This is just a standard .NET Core Web Project.

Comment: when we say auto increment version is each time you build a release on your local environment? what is your definition of auto increment? hence the way I would do it is when I build using Jenkins or Azure Devops, it is set in devops tools to auto increment after each build.

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ To start with, I'd like to figure how to auto-increment on my local environment.

Comment: One simple way I did it previously is reading the current version and increase it by one, so to get version and increment by command line. That said I found this articale not sure if it anser your question, let me know https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/net-core-standard-auto-incrementing-versioning/

Comment: @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ That actually worked.  Thank you.  I am honestly surprised that this functionality isn't baked into the framework.

Comment: I am happy os to hear, I left it as answer so other can get benefit of it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One simple way I did it previously is by reading the current version and increasing it by one, so you get the current version and increment by one using the command line.

With that said, it is possible to do the following for the .net core project:

In your .csproj file, you add the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

In your code, for instance, in your entry point class, add the following:

```
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
```

When you build the code, it will get a version like 1.0.8419.40347.

[image]

To make more customization, check this article: https://sachabarbs.wordpress.com/2020/02/23/net-core-standard-auto-incrementing-versioning/

In addition, I added this link:

[Equivalent to AssemblyInfo in dotnet core/csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42138418/equivalent-to-assemblyinfo-in-dotnet-core-csproj)

And I use this exertion as well for Visual Studio:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PrecisionInfinity.AutomaticVersions

Comment: It seems that secrets don't work in Development with this configuration

Comment: Maybe i did get it. But what does secret has to do with version

Comment: If your application uses secrets, switching the deterministic option to false will break the functionality that reads the secrets at runtime. You would not think that the two are related, but unfortunately, they are.

Answer (score 2):

Maytham's solution is fine, but there's also a solution that allows you to both

- generate the AssemblyInfo from the csproj settings *and*
- auto-fill the file version with the (auto-generated) assembly version:

To do this, you just need to suppress auto-generation of the FileVersion attribute with the `GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute` setting:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.*</AssemblyVersion>
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
</PropertyGroup>
```

(Credit for this technique goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60486611/87698).)

Answer (score 2):

I used this article :
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5260362/NET-Core-Standard-Auto-Incrementing-Versioning

and informations provided here to generate application build number on Year.Month.Day.incremental.

```
<VersionSuffix>$([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString(yyyy.MM.dd.mmff))</VersionSuffix>
<AssemblyVersion Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' == '' ">0.0.0.1</AssemblyVersion>
<AssemblyVersion Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' != '' ">$(VersionSuffix)</AssemblyVersion>
<Version Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' == '' ">0.0.1.0</Version>
<Version Condition=" '$(VersionSuffix)' != '' ">$(VersionSuffix)</Version>

<GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute >false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute >
<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
<Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
<GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyCopyrightAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>true</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is really old, but it's still the first thing that comes up on Google. After reasearching this for too long, I finally found a lightweight solution that let's you use your own custom C# code to define the version.

**Basically, use a T4 template to generate the version number (using any code and logic you like) and then read the result into the version property using an MSBuild static method call in your .csproj file.**

Step-by-step example:

Create a new file on your project's root level called "version.tt" and insert this code:

```
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>
<#
int major = 1;
int minor = 2;
int patch = 3;
int build = (int)((DateTime.UtcNow - DateTime.Parse("2020-01-01")).TotalDays);
string output = major + "." + minor + "." + patch + "." + build;
#>
<#= output #>
```

This should, after saving, immediately create a file named "version.txt" containing a version string like "1.2.3.123" which will be updated automatically by Visual Studio in the future.

Then go into your .csproj and define the version like this:

```
<Version>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(version.txt))</Version>
```