# How to automatically increment the assembly version number in C#

Tags: c#, .net, version, auto

How to automatically increment the assembly version number in C# .

NET6 no longer has AssemblyInfo.cs, as we all know

And i try the answer at
[How to auto increment the version (eg. “1.0.*”) of a .NET Core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63333988/how-to-auto-increment-the-version-eg-1-0-of-a-net-core-project)

it doesn't work

Comment: This article "works" for me: https://scottdorman.blog/2018/08/20/net-core-project-versioning/

Comment: Tool recommendation is off topic. You can find a lot, and GitVersion is also possible, https://gitversion.net/docs/usage/msbuild

Comment: There are a couple answers to [How to auto increment the version (eg. “1.0.*”) of a .NET Core project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63333988/3744182).  Which one(s) did you try, that did not work?  Might you please [edit] your question to show what you tried so far?  If we don't know what you tried that failed -- specifically, a [mcve] -- we're likely to suggest the same things that you already tried.  See [ask].