# VS2010 Deployment project - How to pull Version from AssemblyInfo?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, versioning, setup-deployment

I am using single SharedAssemblyInfo.cs file to share AssemblyVersion for all projects in the solution.

Is there a way to pull that info and update the Deployment project's Version property with the same value?

Comment: This is for VS 2005, but it's probably pretty close to what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306233/how-to-programatically-change-a-projects-product-version