# How to change setup project version (in TFS 2015 [vNext build])

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild, tfs-2015, vnext

for building my project setup file\msi in TFS 2015 i use

devenv Command Line task:

```
solutionPath /build BuildConfiguration /project projectPath
```

My question is how can i change msi version (if it's possible) from that line like ... $(BuildVersion)

Checked MSDN devenv command line (nothing.)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumning you want to change the `ProductVersion` value in `.vdproj` file during build. You are correct that there is no command to change this directly.

You need to use powershell or programatically change the version. Here is a code snippet in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306233/how-to-programatically-change-a-projects-product-version) you can refer to:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    string setupFileName = @"<Replace the path to vdproj file>"; 
    StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(setupFileName); 
    string file = string.Empty; 

    try 
    { 
        Regex expression = new Regex(@"(?:\""ProductCode\"" = 
        \""8.){([\d\w-]+)}"); 
        Regex expression1 = new Regex(@"(?:\""UpgradeCode\"" = 
        \""8.){([\d\w-]+)}"); 
        file = reader.ReadToEnd(); 

        file = expression.Replace(file, "\"ProductCode\" = \"8:{" + 
        Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper() + "}"); 
        file = expression1.Replace(file, "\"UpgradeCode\" = \"8:{" 
        + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().ToUpper() + "}"); 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        // Close the file otherwise the compile may not work 
        reader.Close(); 
    } 

    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(setupFileName); 
    try 
    { 
        tw.Write(file); 
    } 
    finally 
    { 
        // close the stream 
        tw.Close(); 
    } 
 }
```

Or you can refer to the powershell script that replace AssemblyVersion from AssemblyInfo.cs in [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200323/get-and-replace-assemblyversion-from-assemblyinfo-cs) to change `ProductVersion` value in `.vdproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as Cece's solution but with a .vbs script that takes the .vdproj filename as first argument and the version as 2nd argument (**.**.** format) :

```
'Function that generates a new GUID
Function CreateGUID
  Dim TypeLib
  Set TypeLib = CreateObject("Scriptlet.TypeLib")
  CreateGUID = Mid(TypeLib.Guid, 2, 36)
End Function

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

'Read vdproj filename and new version from arguments and generate new Guid
installerFileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
newProductVersion = Wscript.Arguments(1)
newProductCode = CreateGUID()
newPackageCode = CreateGUID()

'Prepare Regexs
Set productVersionRegex = New RegExp
With productVersionRegex
 .Pattern    = Chr(34) & "ProductVersion" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:(.*)" & Chr(34)
 .IgnoreCase = False
End With

Set productCodeRegex = New RegExp
With productCodeRegex
 .Pattern    = Chr(34) & "ProductCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{(.*)}" & Chr(34)
 .IgnoreCase = False
End With

Set packageCodeRegex = New RegExp
With packageCodeRegex
 .Pattern    = Chr(34) & "PackageCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{(.*)}" & Chr(34)
 .IgnoreCase = False
End With

'Read Text from installer file
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(installerFileName, ForReading)
installerText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close

'Replace ProductVersion
newProductVersionString = Chr(34) & "ProductVersion" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:" & newProductVersion & Chr(34)
installerNewText = productVersionRegex.Replace(installerText, newProductVersionString)

'Replace ProductCode Guid
newProductCodeString = Chr(34) & "ProductCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{" & newProductCode & "}" & Chr(34)
installerNewText = productCodeRegex.Replace(installerNewText, newProductCodeString)

'Replace UpgradeCode  Guid
newPackageCodeString = Chr(34) & "PackageCode" & Chr(34) & " = " & Chr(34) & "8:{" & newPackageCode & "}" & Chr(34)
installerNewText = packageCodeRegex.Replace(installerNewText, newPackageCodeString)

'Write new Text in installer file
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(installerFileName, ForWriting)
objFile.Write installerNewText
objFile.Close
```

The script can be called like this :

```
cscript script.vbs Installer.vdproj 1.2.5
```