# obtain current svn revision in webapp

Tags: java, svn, web-applications, revision

what is the best way of displaying/using the revision number in a java webapp?

we just use ant to build our .war archive, no buildserver or such. i'd hope there was some kind if $ref that i could write in a resource file, but this is only updated when the file in question is committed. i need it globally.

what would you recommend? post-commit triggers that update certain files?
custom ant scripts? is there a more non-hacky way of doing this?
or it it better to have my own version number independent of svn.

edit: great suggestions! thanks a lot for the answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There are a couple of Ant tasks that can do this for you.**

[SvnAnt task](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant.html) from tigris is the oldest.

Documentation is [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svn.html#info) - in particular take a look at the `info` element which exposes the Subversion repository's revision number as an Ant property which it calls `rev`.  You can write this value to your resouces file using the normal Ant substituion mechanisms.

Someone has also put up a [simillar (simpler) task](http://code.google.com/p/svntask/) on google code hosting - never used it though so can't comment.

Either of these seem like the neatest way to me if you already have Ant in your build.

Answer (score 6):

We use the following ant task to include the svn version in a attribute in the jar, along with the version of other packages that are being used

```
<target name="package" depends="compile" description="Package up the project as a jar">
<!-- Create the subversion version string -->
<exec executable="svnversion" failifexecutionfails="no" outputproperty="version">
  <arg value="."/> 
  <arg value="-n"/>
</exec>
<!-- Create the time stamp -->
<tstamp>
  <format property="timeAndDate" pattern="HH:mm d-MMMM-yyyy"/>
</tstamp>

<jar destfile="simfraserv.jar">
  <manifest>
    <attribute name="Built-By"                value="${user.name} on ${time.date}" />
    <attribute name="Implementation-Version"  value="${svn.version}" />
    <attribute name="Implementation-Java"     value="${java.vendor} ${java.version}" />
    <attribute name="Implementation-Build-OS" value="${os.name} ${os.arch} ${os.version}" />
    <attribute name="JVM-Version"             value="${common.sourcelevel}+" />        
  </manifest>
  <fileset dir="bin">
    <include name="**/*.class"/>
  </fileset>
  <fileset dir="src">
    <include name="**"/>
  </fileset>
</jar>
</target>
```

And then you can access it in your webapp like this

```
String version = this.getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVersion();
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ant you can define this task:

```
 <target name="version">
<exec executable="svn" output="svninfo.xml" failonerror="true">
  <arg line="info --xml" />
</exec>
<xmlproperty file="svninfo.xml" collapseattributes="true" />
<echo message="SVN Revision: ${info.entry.commit.revision}"/>
<property name="revision" value="${info.entry.commit.revision}" />
</target>
```

and you the revision value where you want.

Comment: I Prefer this solution because it is simple and out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111436/how-can-i-get-the-svn-revision-number-in-php).

My favourite from that thread is just dumping `$Id:$` in your code where you want the revision ID. SVN will populate that with the real data when you do an export.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows you could look at SubWCRev.exe which comes with tortoise.

It gives the current repository revision and will replace $WCREV$ with said, you could include this in your web.xml as say a context param and then get it from there.

Answer (score 0):

Before the webapp is packaged, run svn info and redirect the output to some file in WEB-INF/classes. When the webapp starts up, parse this file and have it stashed away in the servlet context or some similar place. In the footer of every page, display this version - if you are using something like Tiles or SiteMesh, this change needs to be done only in one file.

Maven users can try the maven-buildnumber plugin.