# Revision number with SVN

Tags: java, svn, ant, version-control, revision

I'm working with an application written in Java, and using Subversion as VCS. What I want to do, is to get latest revision number in header of application (ex. "MyApp rev.2000").

I've tried to use svn:keywords, but it shows only the latest revision number of that one specific file, where it is used - for example, if i have some main class with this property and current revision is 5, and in the next commit I won't change that class but only some others, revision number will remain the same (5).

Is there any subversion keyword or something like this, which can give me latest revision of all project? I'm using Ant, so maven plugins won't help.

Comment: For Ant-related task, [this question and it's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166322/obtain-current-svn-revision-in-webapp) are better suited, IMNSHO

Comment: For Java, you can also consider using [SvnRev](http://www.compuphase.com/svnrev.htm)