# How can my iphone app detect its own version number?

Tags: iphone, ios, version

I'm writing an iPhone app.  It's already been published, but I would like to add a feature where its version number is displayed.

I'd rather not have to do this manually with each version I release...

Is there a way in objective-C to find out what the version is of my app?

Comment: This question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16888788/2890157.

Comment: .. the linked question is 4 year later, so the real issue here is that cmos never *accepted* an answer. Regardless, the linked question's answers are useful, as are the answers here. On both threads, look beyond first answer - sometimes there is more up-to-date info on a later answer.

Answer (score 224):

[As I describe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372218/insert-subversion-revision-number-in-xcode#414792), I use a script to rewrite a header file with my current Subversion revision number.  That revision number is stored in the kRevisionNumber constant.  I can then access the version and revision number using something similar to the following:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@ (%@)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"], kRevisionNumber]
```

which will create a string of the format "Version 1.0 (51)".

Comment: That returned my build version so I used this one. [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]

Comment: CFBundleVersion is incorrect, because Xcode erroneously populates that plist entry with the build number and not the version number. jspooner is correct.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851660/version-vs-build-in-xcode-4 for a great explanation of Version vs Build numbers. Confirms that `CFBundleShortVersionString` what you'd normally want for 'version' and `CFBundleVersion` for Build number.

Comment: kRevisionNumber doen't seem to work for me. To get the output specified I did this (using @jspooner 's fix): `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version: %@ (%@)", [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"], [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]]`

Answer (score 151):

Building on Brad Larson's answer, if you have major and minor version info stored in the info plist (as I did on a particular project), this worked well for me:

```
- (NSString *)appNameAndVersionNumberDisplayString {
    NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary];
    NSString *appDisplayName = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleDisplayName"];
    NSString *majorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
    NSString *minorVersion = [infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, Version %@ (%@)", 
                appDisplayName, majorVersion, minorVersion];
}
```

Now revving a minor version manually can be a pain, and so using a source repository revision number trick is ideal. If you've not tied that in (as I hadn't), the above snippet can be useful. It also pulls out the app's display name.

Answer (score 60):

Swift version for both separately:

*Swift 3*

```
let versionNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
let buildNumber = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as! String
```

---

*Swift 2*

```
let versionNumber = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
let buildNumber = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleVersion") as! String
```

Its included in this repo, check it out:

https://github.com/goktugyil/EZSwiftExtensions

Answer (score 43):

This is what I did in my application

```
NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Hopefully this simple answer will help somebody...

Comment: This return the build name, not version

Comment: @chancyWu, CFBundleShortVersionString appears to give the version.

Answer (score 31):

You can specify the `CFBundleShortVersionString` string in your plist.info and read that programmatically using the [provided API](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AccessingaBundlesContents/AccessingaBundlesContents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH104-123785).

Answer (score 30):

There are two things - build version and app version.

1. To get App version:

   ```
   NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
   ```
2. To get Build version:

   ```
   NSString *buildVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
   ```

Comment: Is there any difference between these two? They both return the same for me.

Comment: yes , may be your build number and app version are same in settings .

Comment: Okay, I only have one setting in my RAKEFILE - app.version (I'm using RubyMotion). I guess either will do for my needs. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, mate. Worked smoothly.

Comment: FYI It's preferable to use `objectForInfoDictionaryKey:` instead of `infoDictionary] objectForKey:` because the former returns the localised value (if there is one). Probably won't make a difference here though ;)

Answer (score 18):

A succinct way to obtain a version string in *X.Y.Z* format is:

```
[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

Or, for just *X.Y:*

```
[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

Both of these snippets returns strings that you would assign to your label object's text property, e.g.

```
myLabel.text = [NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary[@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Answer (score 17):

```
// Syncs with App Store and Xcode Project Settings Input
NSString *appVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try using dictionary as:-

```
NSDictionary *infoDictionary = [[NSBundle mainBundle]infoDictionary];

NSString *buildVersion = infoDictionary[(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
NSString *bundleName = infoDictionary[(NSString *)kCFBundleNameKey]
```

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 5:**

There are two things - App version and build version

- To get App version:

  ```
   if let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
        // present appVersion
  }
  ```
- To get Build version:

  ```
   if let buildVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
        // present buildVersion
   }
  ```

Thanks `@Brad Larson♦` a lot

Answer (score 4):

Read the info.plist file of your app and get the value for key CFBundleShortVersionString. Reading info.plist will give you an NSDictionary object

Answer (score 4):

You can use the infoDictionary which gets the version details from info.plist of you app. This code works for swift 3. Just call this method and display the version in any preferred UI element.

```
Swift-3  

func getVersion() -> String {
    let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
    let version = dictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
    let build = dictionary["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
    return "v\(version).\(build)"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need a **combination** of both **version *and* build num**, here's a short way using **Swift 3**:

```
let appVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleShortVersionString"]!
let buildNum = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"]!
let versionInfo = "\(appVersion) (build \(buildNum))"
// versionInfo is now something like "2.3.0 (build 17)"
```

Add an `as! String` to the end of either the `appVersion` or `buildNum` line to get only that portion as a `String` object. No need for that though if you're looking for the full `versionInfo`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
func getAppVersion() -> String {
    let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
    let versionValue = dictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] ?? "0"
    let buildValue = dictionary["CFBundleVersion"] ?? "0"
    return "\(versionValue) (build \(buildValue))"
}
```

Based on @rajat chauhan answer without forced cast to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good thing to handle with a revision control system. That way when you get a bug report from a user, you can check out that revision of code and (hopefully) reproduce the bug running the exact same code as the user.

The idea is that every time you do a build, you will run a script that gets the current revision number of your code and updates a file within your project (usually with some form of token replacement). You can then write an error handling routine that always includes the revision number in the error output, or you can display it on an "About" page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```