# Internal versioning for iphone apps

Tags: iphone, plist

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to version an iphone application aside from using the "Bundle Version" and "Bundle Version short string". I'm finding difficulty relying on these values to version control my application b/c I have multiple variations (lite, paid) of the same app. Also the current implementation of itunes connect does not allow you to change the version number of an update once you set it, so if you decide to replace an update w/ a new binary, your stuck using the same version number you started with.

I was thinking of adding an key-value pair into the info.plist file, but I'm not sure if I am allowed to add new key-value pairs into the info.plist. The other alternative I can think of is to create my own plist for app settings.

If there are better ways to achieve this, I'm open to hear them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely add your own key/value pairs to the info.plist. Make sure to prefix the keys to help ensure your keys don't collide with any Apple-used keys.

Answer (score 1):

Each version of my app has it's own Info.plist file and they share the same code base in xcode, using multiple targets for building. They can all have their own version numbers using the "Bundle Version" setting this way.

Here's a post and tutorial about the setup:

http://www.codza.com/free-iphone-app-version-from-the-same-xcode-project

I think you could add your own key to the Info.plist (that file is not bundled with your app), but I don't see why that would be better than using the "Bundle Version" key that's already there.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the items discussed in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458632/how-can-my-iphone-app-detect-its-own-version-number) might be of use to you in this case.