# Version and Build Information Error Xcode 4

Tags: shell, xcode4, version-numbering, build-numbers

I'm using Xcode 4.3 and I have followed this user's steps to create the script:

[Version vs build in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851660/version-vs-build-in-xcode-4)

For whatever reason it does not look like I can leave a comment there. As the answer area in StackOverlow is not a forum/discussion I'm a bit forced to ask a question based off that answer.

In Step 7 he cites 2 ways to increment Build Version: Number and Hex Number

```
#!/bin/bash    
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash    
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$((0x$buildNumber)) 
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1)) 
buildNumber=$(printf "%X" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Both are returning the exact same shell error:

```
syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I went the summary tab and both version and build were 1.0. If I change this to just "1" the error is "line 4 1 + 1: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is " + 1")

What am I doing wrong and what can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your build number has a floating point value, so change your code to

```
#!/bin/bash    
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=`echo $buildNumber +1|bc`
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

as suggested in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9196647/184245).