# Auto-Increment Build Number for Multiple Targets in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, bash, xcode4

I have a "Free" and "Paid" version of my app, and I want to auto-increment both of the build numbers simultaneously, because sometimes I test with the "Free" version and sometimes I test with the "Paid" version depending on what I am doing. These are essentially the same codebase, I just have two targets with a preprocessor directive defined with the "Paid" version to unlock certain things.

I am using the code in this question:
[Version vs build in XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851660/version-vs-build-in-xcode-4)

```
#!/bin/bash    
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

I think I just need to add two more lines specifying the path to the other `$INFOPLIST_FILE` along the lines of:

```
 "Print CFBundleVersion" "NEW_PATH/$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

and increment it, but how do I get the path to one target's Plist when I am building the other?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what do you actually mean by path?

Comment: I meant the file path, i.e. "~/Projects/iOSApp/App."
I figured out the question and answered below, if you're interested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to use the `SRCROOT` variable. This will give you the base directory for the project. From there, you need to manually specify the location of the info.plist files you wish to use, and run the `PlistBuddy -c` command with that path.

Here is an example that increments the "Free" version first and then increments the "Paid" version:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"

buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$SRCROOT/Pro-Info.plist")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/Pro-Info.plist"
```

You need to make sure you inverse the script for each target, so it uses the `$INFOPLIST_FILE` variable on the current target and you are specifying the location of the others. You could probably store these in custom variables or specify each one instead of using the `$INFOPLIST_FILE` variable at all, but they all do essentially the same thing.

Answer (score 14):

An update for the latest Xcode, first change "Versioning System" to "Apple Generic" in "Build Settings" tab for all of your targets.
[image: versioning system: Apple Generic]

And add this line in "Run Script" of "Build Phases" tab for all of your targets:

```
agvtool next-version -all
```

[image: agvtool increments build number for all targets]
agvtool will do the increment job for you!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Did you have a problem when using this command builds are being cancelled? I use Xcode 11.1

Comment: @A.Buksha I have the same problem and was wondering what was causing it...

Comment: Is necessary to set the "Current Version Project" key to start to work

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing issue with avgtool, Please check this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60073040/208308

I have solved my issue with the script shared in the above link without the use of avgtool.

Answer (score 0):

To increment build number in the Xcode Server I am using

0. Set: **Current Project Version = 1** and **Version System = Apple Generic**. Can be found more in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html).
1. Right click on the bot and choose **Edit Bot...**
2. Open **Triggers** tab and add Pre-Integration Script
3. Give a **name** (example: Set Build Version) and write script:

> ```
> cd $XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR # Change directory to project path 
> xcrun agvtool new-version -all $XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER # Set build version same as integration number
> ```

[image: Build number incremental using Xcode Bot]