# Getting version and build information with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, nsbundle

I am attempting to gain access to the main `NSBundle` to retrieve **version** and **build** information. Thing is, I want to try it in Swift, I know how to retrieve it in Objective-C with:

```objectivec
text = [NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Yet I don't know where to start with Swift, I have attempted to write it in the new syntax with no avail.

Comment: Show the attempts you've already made. It's very similar to the Objective-C implementation.

Comment: Jan 2017 swift 2.3 :        let sVer = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
        let sBuild = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
        self.myVersionLabel.text = String(format: "Version %@  Build %@", sVer!, sBuild!)

Answer (score 186, accepted):

What was wrong with the Swift syntax? This seems to work:

```
if let text = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
    print(text)
}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I guess it might be more natural as a `let` but it otherwise looks correct.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the "as String" so the variable would accept it as a string. Thank you.

Comment: That seems to be broken with XCode 6 beta 3

Comment: This worked for me in Xcode 6 beta 5: `let text = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary["CFBundleVersion"]! as String`

Comment: @Dean It looks like they changed infoDictionary to return an optional. I've edited the answer

Comment: Is it safe to force unwrap the returned value? Could it ever be nil?

Comment: @Tommy although my answer comes almost a decade after your question: The question is about version _and_ build number. That's probably why it was downvoted. The answer right below this should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 135):

**Swift 3/4 Version**

```
func version() -> String {
    let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!
    let version = dictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as! String
    let build = dictionary["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
    return "\(version) build \(build)"
}
```

---

**Swift 2.x Version**

```
func version() -> String {
    let dictionary = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary!
    let version = dictionary["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as String
    let build = dictionary["CFBundleVersion"] as String
    return "\(version) build \(build)"
}
```

as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7309349/8047).

Comment: You get the same key twice, should use "CFBundleVersion" for version. I guess it is a copy/past typo :)

Comment: Thanks @foOg it was a typo. In fact it's backwards: the short one is the version, the regular one is the build. Weird, I know.

Comment: Swift 3 version .  if let infoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info.plist", ofType: nil),
            let infoAttr = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: infoPath),
            let infoDate = infoAttr[.creationDate] as? Date
        {
            return infoDate
        }
        return Date()

Answer (score 29):

**ab Swift 5.0**

I created a wrapper to get some *app related strings* at one place in all my apps, called **AppInfo**.

```
/// Wrapper to get some app related strings at one place.
struct AppInfo {

   /// Returns the official app name, defined in your project data.
   var appName : String {
       return readFromInfoPlist(withKey: "CFBundleName") ?? "(unknown app name)"
   }

   /// Return the official app display name, eventually defined in your 'infoplist'.
   var displayName : String {
       return readFromInfoPlist(withKey: "CFBundleDisplayName") ?? "(unknown app display name)"
   }

   /// Returns the official version, defined in your project data.
   var version : String {
       return readFromInfoPlist(withKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") ?? "(unknown app version)"
   }

   /// Returns the official 'build', defined in your project data.
   var build : String {
       return readFromInfoPlist(withKey: "CFBundleVersion") ?? "(unknown build number)"
   }

   /// Returns the minimum OS version defined in your project data.
   var minimumOSVersion : String {
    return readFromInfoPlist(withKey: "MinimumOSVersion") ?? "(unknown minimum OSVersion)"
   }

   /// Returns the copyright notice eventually defined in your project data.
   var copyrightNotice : String {
       return readFromInfoPlist(withKey: "NSHumanReadableCopyright") ?? "(unknown copyright notice)"
   }

   /// Returns the official bundle identifier defined in your project data.
   var bundleIdentifier : String {
       return readFromInfoPlist(withKey: "CFBundleIdentifier") ?? "(unknown bundle identifier)"
   }

   var developer : String { return "my awesome name" }

   // MARK: - Private stuff

   // lets hold a reference to the Info.plist of the app as Dictionary
   private let infoPlistDictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary

   /// Retrieves and returns associated values (of Type String) from info.Plist of the app.
   private func readFromInfoPlist(withKey key: String) -> String? {
    return infoPlistDictionary?[key] as? String
   }
}
```

**Nutzung:**

```
print("Name of the app: \(AppInfo().appName)")
```

Comment: When in Swift a value is not available nil is used. IMO you should return nil instead of custom placeholder strings.

Comment: Thats why it is a wrapper: To always get something back. The nil-situation is not really "destroyed",it is still there, but already pre-handled. Otherwise you would have to handle the "nil"-situation in another place in your app.

Comment: thanks bud.  also, you last curly brace is outside the code block.  :)

Comment: app name can be also `CFBundleDisplayName`

Answer (score 18):

For the final release of Xcode 6 use

```
NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
```

The "?" character after infoDictionary is important here

Comment: Damn. I sure do love this whole "optional?, unwrap!" system, it is crystal clear and so easy to read!

Comment: @JeroenBouma And that hard-coded string is nice too.

Answer (score 16):

Here is simple way to get Build and version.

**For Swift 4.X**

```
 if let version = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String {
     print(version)
   }

 if let build = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String {
     print(build)
   }
```

**For Objective C**

```
NSString *build = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];

NSString * currentVersion = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Let me know if any issue. This is working for me.

Answer (score 14):

Swifty way for `AppName`, `AppVersion` and `BuildNumber`...

```
if let dict = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary {
   if let version = dict["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String,
       let bundleVersion = dict["CFBundleVersion"] as? String,
       let appName = dict["CFBundleName"] as? String {
           return "You're using \(appName) v\(version) (Build \(bundleVersion))."
   }
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to unwrap the values? To my knowledge, it's impossible for any of those values to be nil

Comment: @Michael some people ALWAYS unwrap optional values. Some people say you're right.

Comment: `Bundle.main` had an empty `infoDictionary` for me; maybe because I'm doing it from within a framework, not an executable or app? `Bundle(for: MyClass.self)` contains the expected values.

Answer (score 8):

In swift, I would make it as extension for UIApplication, like this:

```
extension UIApplication {

    func applicationVersion() -> String {

        return NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
    }

    func applicationBuild() -> String {

        return NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey(kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as! String
    }

    func versionBuild() -> String {

        let version = self.applicationVersion()
        let build = self.applicationBuild()

        return "v\(version)(\(build))"
    }
}
```

Then you can just use following to get everything you need:

```
let version = UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationVersion() // 1
let build = UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationBuild() // 80
let both = UIApplication.sharedApplication.versionBuild() // 1(80)
```

Answer (score 7):

//Returns app's version number

```
public static var appVersion: String? {
    return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as? String
}
```

//Return app's build number

```
public static var appBuild: String? {
    return Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as? String
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to define in the AppDelegate the variables:

```
var applicationVersion:String {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
}
var applicationBuild:String  {
    return NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey(kCFBundleVersionKey as String) as! String
}
var versionBuild:String  {
    let version = self.applicationVersion
    let build = self.applicationBuild
    return "version:\(version) build:(\(build))"
}
```

that can be referenced as variables in the AppDelegate

Answer (score 2):

This code works for Swift 3, Xcode 8:

```
let version = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") ?? "0"
let build = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") ?? "0"
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3,Replace NSBundle with Bundle and mainBundle is replaced simply by main.

```
let AppVersion = Bundle.main.infoDictionary!["CFBundleVersion"] as! String
```

Answer (score 1):

[Update: Xcode 6.3.1] I tried all of the above and none of these work in Xcode 6.3.1 but I found that this does:

```
(NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String)!
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 :

```
let textVersion
 = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["CFBundleVersion"] as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

SWIFT 3 Version

```
if let infoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info.plist", ofType: nil),
        let infoAttr = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: infoPath),
        let infoDate = infoAttr[.creationDate] as? Date
{
    return infoDate
}
return Date()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get version from Framework's bundle**

To have result for framework you can use

[[Access to Framework bundle]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67469835/4770877)

```
//inside framework
let version = bundle.infoDictionary?["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 100% working tested**

You can get that easily by using single variable and make it public. You can use it everywhere you want.

(I am getting here User Agent for API header)

```
public let userAgent: String = {
    if let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary {
        let executable = info[kCFBundleExecutableKey as String] as? String ?? "Unknown"
        let bundle = info[kCFBundleIdentifierKey as String] as? String ?? "Unknown"
        let appVersion = info["CFBundleShortVersionString"] as? String ?? "Unknown"
        let appBuild = info[kCFBundleVersionKey as String] as? String ?? "Unknown"

        let osNameVersion: String = {
            let version = ProcessInfo.processInfo.operatingSystemVersion
            let versionString = "\(version.majorVersion).\(version.minorVersion).\(version.patchVersion)"

            let osName: String = {
                #if os(iOS)
                    return "iOS"
                #elseif os(watchOS)
                    return "watchOS"
                #elseif os(tvOS)
                    return "tvOS"
                #elseif os(macOS)
                    return "OS X"
                #elseif os(Linux)
                    return "Linux"
                #else
                    return "Unknown"
                #endif
            }()

            return "\(osName) \(versionString)"
        }()


        return "\(executable)/\(appVersion) (\(bundle); build:\(appBuild); \(osNameVersion)) "
    }

    return "MyApp"
}()
```

**Output:**

```
"User-Agent": "MyApp/4.6.0 (com.app.myapp; build:4.6.0.0; iOS 15.2.0) "
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin Multiplatform:**

androidMain:

```kotlin
import com.txconnected.mobox.component.core.BuildConfig

actual val buildType: BuildType get() {
    return BuildType.fromString(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE)
}
```

commonMain:

```
enum class BuildType {
    DEBUG,
    RELEASE,
    ;

    companion object {
        fun fromString(value: String): BuildType {
            return when (value) {
                "debug" -> DEBUG
                "release" -> RELEASE
                else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown build type: $value")
            }
        }
    }
}

expect val buildType: BuildType

fun BuildType.isDebug(): Boolean {
    return this == BuildType.DEBUG
}
```

iosMain:

```
import platform.Foundation.NSBundle

actual val buildType: BuildType get() {
    val build = NSBundle.mainBundle.infoDictionary?.get("CFBundleVersion") as? String ?: "release"
    return BuildType.fromString(build)
}
```