# How to retrieve a file/resource in a iOS framework bundle from a main program?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I use methods about creating a universal binary framework for iOS development to distribute a library. I would also like to add files in the framework, and load them in the main program (an SSL certificate actually). This is related to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707429/can-you-reference-xib-files-from-static-libraries-on-the-iphone), the main difference is that I want to include something else than a XIB.

If we read the thread related to the linked post, it seems it is not possible. However, the following [blog article](http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/iphone/iPhone_Framework_Support.20081202.html) was mentioned; we can read:

> "Static frameworks are not a full replacement for standard frameworks
>   -- standard methods for accessing the framework resources, such as `+[NSBundle bundleForClass:]` will not return the expected bundle. The bundle path is determined by querying dyld for the library path
>   corresponding to the symbol address -- In the case of static linking,
>   this will return the path to the binary into which the static library
>   was linked. Additionally, `NSBundle/CFBundle` will examine the previous
>   stack from for the return address, and use that return address to
>   determine the calling code's dyld binary path. Given these
>   restrictions, some work-arounds are possible, such as using `-[NSBundle privateFrameworkPath]`
>   to locate the path to the embedded framework."

I am a beginner in iOS development, and I struggle in using such a mechanism. Using the `privateFrameworksPath` returns a path indeed, but I do not know what to do next to locate the file I want to load.

It is something like that:

```
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString * path = [bundle privateFrameworksPath]; // Works, return something like .../Frameworks
NSString * file = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFramework.framework/Versions/A/my-cert.der"]; 
NSData * trustedCertData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file]; // Returns nil
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The following code worked for me in a similar case

```
NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString * file = [bundle pathForResource:@"my-cert" ofType:@"der"];; 
NSData * trustedCertData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[file stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

The `NSBundle bundleForClass:` method returns a bundle for the framework of the current class. So if you call this method from within MyFramework you won't need to append the path with `MyFramework.framework` again, but you would have caught that debugging if that was your problem.

Also the dash in `my-cert.der` may need to be replaced with the % equivelent. hence the `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` call.

Answer (score 1):

**Access to Framework bundle**

The key point is to pass any `metatype`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67459704/4770877) of class which belongs to framework

Objective-C

```
NSBundle *someBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[SomeFrameworkClass class]];
```

Swift

```
//via public framework's class
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: SomeFrameworkClass.self)
//or via Bundle Identifier(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.someid") 
//or if it is called from the framework
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)

//working with bundle as usual
```

[[Vocabulary]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59216151/4770877)