# How to use Localizable.strings stored in a CocoaTouch Framework?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, multilingual, nslocalizedstring

I'd like to add multi-language support to a CocoaTouch Framework.

The problem: The *Localizable.strings* file I created only gets used by **NSLocalizedString** when it's part of the main app and its target. I'd like to store it inside the Framework to keep things separate.

How can I use the **Localizable.strings** when placed inside a CocoaTouch Framework?

Answer (score 15):

Use:

```
NSLocalizedString("Good", tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self), value: "", comment: "")
```

or you can create public func like this:

```
class func POLocalized(key: String) -> String{
    let s =  NSLocalizedString(key, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle(forClass: self.classForCoder()), value: "", comment: "")
    return s
}
```

example of use:

```
let locString = POLocalized("key")
```

Comment: Do not use NSBundle(forClass: self) for public classes, because some Main bundle classes can inherit framework class and NSBundle(forClass: self) will point to main bundle, not the framework.

Comment: In this case u can use NSBundle(identifier: "FRAMEWORK_ID")

Comment: What does the `value` parameter represent? The current Apple docs do not explain...

Comment: It's a default value returned if the string is not found in the given table.

Comment: For those who might wonder: No matter how much localizations your framework may contain, they will not be returned by `NSLocalizedString` (with the solution above) if your project itself is not targeting the desired language also.

Answer (score 7):

This can be done by specifying the bundle identifier of the framework in the `NSLocalizedString` constructor.

```
if let bundle: NSBundle = NSBundle(identifier: "com.mycompany.TheFramework") {
    let string = NSLocalizedString("key", tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
    print(string)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add this struct to your codebase:

```
internal struct InternalConstants {
    private class EmptyClass {}
    static let bundle = Bundle(for: InternalConstants.EmptyClass.self)
}
```

And then use optional bundle param to specify the location of your string file:

```
let yourString = NSLocalizedString("Hello", bundle: InternalConstants.bundle, comment: "")
```

`Bundle.main` is the default value if you don't use `bundle` param in your `NSLocalizedString` constructor.

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem, or how this differs from the existing answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22869358)

Answer (score 0):

**Get Localizable.strings from framework**

A main point is to use Framework's bundle - bundle where strings(`Localizable.string`) are located

[[Access to Framework bundle]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67469835/4770877)

```
//e.g.
let someString = NSLocalizedString("some_string_id", tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle(identifier: "com.something")!, value: "", comment: "")
```

extension variant

```
extension String {
    public var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle(identifier: "com.something")!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}

//using
let someString = "some_string_id".localized
```