# Can not localize String due to compiler optimization?

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I defined iTunes categories in my code like this:

```
public enum ItunesCategoryType: Int {
    case arts = 1
    case business = 8
    case comedy = 14
    case education = 15
    case gamesHobbies = 21
    case governmentOrganizations = 27
    case health = 32
    case kidsFamily = 37
    case music = 38
    case newsPolitics = 39
    case religionSpirituality = 40
    case scienceMedicine = 48
    case societyCulture = 52
    case sportsRecreation = 57
    case technology = 62
    case tvFilm = 67
}

public struct ItunesCategory {
    public var id: Int {
        return type.rawValue
    }
    public let type: ItunesCategoryType
    public var name: String {
        switch type {
        case .arts: return NSLocalizedString("arts", value: "Arts", comment: "")
        case .business: return NSLocalizedString("business", value: "Business", comment: "")
        case .comedy: return NSLocalizedString("comedy", value: "Comedy", comment: "")
        case .education: return NSLocalizedString("education", value: "Education", comment: "")
        case .gamesHobbies: return NSLocalizedString("games-hobbies", value: "Games & Hobbies", comment: "")
        case .governmentOrganizations: return NSLocalizedString("government-organizations", value: "Government & Organizations", comment: "")
        case .health: return NSLocalizedString("health", value: "Health", comment: "")
        case .kidsFamily: return NSLocalizedString("kids-family", value: "Kids & Family", comment: "")
        case .music: return NSLocalizedString("music", value: "Music", comment: "")
        case .newsPolitics: return NSLocalizedString("news-politics", value: "News & Politics", comment: "")
        case .religionSpirituality: return NSLocalizedString("religion-spirituality", value: "Religion & Spirituality", comment: "")
        case .scienceMedicine: return NSLocalizedString("science-medicine", value: "Science & Medicine", comment: "")
        case .societyCulture: return NSLocalizedString("society-culture", value: "Society & Culture", comment: "")
        case .sportsRecreation: return NSLocalizedString("sports-recreation", value: "Sports & Recreation", comment: "")
        case .technology: return NSLocalizedString("techology", value: "Technology", comment: "")
        case .tvFilm: return NSLocalizedString("tv-film", value: "TV & Film", comment: "")
        }
    }

    public init(type: ItunesCategoryType) {
        self.type = type
    }
}
```

As you can see I want the category names to be localized.

`Localizable.strings` contains (among others)

```
"arts" = "Kunst";
```

Somewhere in my code I run this:

```
print(ItunesCategory(type: .arts).name)
```

I run my app with Application Language and Region set to German. This does not print the translated value. It prints `Arts` instead of `Kunst`.

Why does it not print the correctly localized String? I assume this is due to compiler optimizations?

Comment: Have you tried NSLocalizedString("arts", comment: "") instead of NSLocalizedString("arts", value: "Arts", comment: "") ?

Comment: Yes I have tried that. In this case it prints `arts`.

Comment: This should work..may be you missed outside of the question

Comment: Compiler optimizations have nothing to do with it. Are your `Localizable.strings` files placed correctly? Do you have other languages localized? If so, do they work? Are you running ond device or simulator? Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding your project, doing a fresh install?

Comment: @ThatlazyiOSGuy웃 You are correct. I was missing on something else I did not know. The localisation was placed inside a Framework. I did not define a bundle for NSLocalizedString. Therefore the localised Strings could not be found. This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724714/how-to-use-localizable-strings-stored-in-a-cocoatouch-framework

Answer (score 0):

This is no compiler issue. The localisation was placed inside a Framework. I did not define a bundle for NSLocalizedString. Therefore the localised Strings could not be found.

[How to use Localizable.strings stored in a CocoaTouch Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28724714/how-to-use-localizable-strings-stored-in-a-cocoatouch-framework)