# Swift - what's the difference between metatype .Type and .self?

Tags: swift, debugging, reflection, dynamictype, metatype

What's the difference between metatype `.Type` and `.self` in Swift?

Do `.self` and `.Type` return a `struct`?

I understand that `.self` can be used to check with `dynamicType`.  How do you use `.Type`?

Comment: Some of the info at the bottom of this might be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-ID457

Comment: @Pops I read that before posting this question.

Comment: Might read this: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_type_reference Note especially the summary at the end of the section.

Comment: @matt Good stuff, thank you.

Comment: @Boon thanks, glad if it helps. I get confused too - that's why I put the summary at the end!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Here is a quick example:

```
func printType<T>(of type: T.Type) {
    // or you could do "\(T.self)" directly and
    // replace `type` parameter with an underscore
    print("\(type)") 
} 

printType(of: Int.self) // this should print Swift.Int


func printInstanceDescription<T>(of instance: T) {
    print("\(instance)")
} 

printInstanceDescription(of: 42) // this should print 42
```

Let's say that each entity is represented by two things:

- Type: `# entitiy name #`
- Metatype: `# entity name # .Type`

> A metatype type refers to the type of any type, including class types, structure types, enumeration types, and protocol types.
>
> [Source.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html)

You can quickly notice that this is recursive and there can by types like `(((T.Type).Type).Type)` and so on.

`.Type` returns an instance of a metatype.

There are two ways we can get an instance of a metatype:

- Call `.self` on a concrete type like `Int.self` which will create a
  **static** metatype instance `Int.Type`.
- Get the **dynamic** metatype instance from any instance through
  `type(of: someInstance)`.

Dangerous area:

```
struct S {}
protocol P {}

print("\(type(of: S.self))")      // S.Type
print("\(type(of: S.Type.self))") // S.Type.Type
print("\(type(of: P.self))")      // P.Protocol
print("\(type(of: P.Type.self))") // P.Type.Protocol
```

`.Protocol` is yet another metatype which only exisits in context of protocols. That said, there is no way how we can express that we want only `P.Type`. This prevents all generic algorithms to work with protocol metatypes and can lead to runtime crashes.

For more curious people:

The `type(of:)` function is actually handled by the compiler because of the inconsistency `.Protocol` creates.

```
// This implementation is never used, since calls to `Swift.type(of:)` are
// resolved as a special case by the type checker.
public func type<T, Metatype>(of value: T) -> Metatype { ... }
```

Comment: You're welcome :) There is also a `.dynamicType`. This one is to get the last level type of your instance at runtime. Lets say you have this: `let instance : UIView = CustomUIView()` then you will call `instance.dynamicType` somewhere and then you'll get `CustomUIView` and not `UIView`. ;)

Comment: Is .Type return a class or a struct or both?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's a struct, enum or class. It will return the type for that thing. If you have `struct A {}` then `A.self` will return `A`.

Comment: `.Type` is not magic, it says that you will pass/have a metatype for a specific type and not it's instance. `.self` is there to get this metatype. It's kinda hard to explain with all these type suffixes everywhere. :D

Comment: By compiler magic I mean Type is not really a thing we can see a definition of (like we can with Dictionary or Array)

Comment: I feel like the word 'meta' here is misleading. Replacing 'metatype' with 'typeName' in Apple's documentation will reduce the confusion

Comment: So basically you use `.Type` for parameters and `.self` for arguments? (https://stackoverflow.com/a/156787/865175)

Comment: @DevAndArtist can I clarify with you what your comment meant? is it that ```A.self``` returns ```A.Type``` and the ```.Type``` would then return the type of A which in the end would be ```A```?

Answer (score 60):

First and foremost see Apple docs on [`type(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type)

The function's signature is interesting:

```
func type<T, Metatype>(of value: T) -> Metatype
```

---

**Where is it used?**

If you are writing/creating a function that accepts a *type* e.g. `UIView.Type`, **not** an instance e.g. `UIView()` then to you would write `T.Type` as the type of the parameter. What it expects as a parameter can be: `String.self`, `CustomTableView.self`, `someOtherClass.self`.

## But why would a function ever need a type?

*Normally* a function which requires a type, is a function that **instantiates** objects for you. I can think of a few examples:

1. [register](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614888-register) function from tableview

```
tableView.register(CustomTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
```

Notice that you passed `CustomTableViewCell.self`. If later on you try to dequeue a tableView of type `CustomTableViewCell` but didn't register `CustomTableViewCell` type then it would crash because the tableView hasn't dequeued/instantiated any tableviewcells of `CustomTableViewCell` type.

2. [decode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder) function from [JSONDecoder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder). Example is from the link

```
struct GroceryProduct: Codable {
    var name: String
    var points: Int
    var description: String?
}

let json = """
{
    "name": "Durian",
    "points": 600,
    "description": "A fruit with a distinctive scent."
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let product = try decoder.decode(GroceryProduct.self, from: json)

print(product.name)
```

Notice `try decoder.decode(GroceryProduct.self, from: json)`. Because you passed `GroceryProduct.self` it knows that it needs to instantiate an object of type `GroceryProduct`. If it can't then it would throw an error. For more on `JSONDecoder` see this [well written answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59863576/5175709)

3. Trying to find a value of a certain class type. Example trying to find a viewController of a certain type among all viewcontrollers of a navigationController:

```
func popBackTo<T>(type: T.Type, in nav: UINavigationController? = nil, completion: ((T?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    let nav = window?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    guard let nav = nav, let destinationVC = nav.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is T }) else {
        return
    }
    nav.popToViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
}

# Example call site:
popBackTo(LoginVC.self)
```

4. As an alternate workaround for where types are needed see the following question: [Swift can't infer generic type when generic type is being passed through a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53748822). The accepted answer offers an interesting alternative.

---

More about the internals and how it works:

## .Type

> The metatype of a class, structure, or enumeration type is the name of
> that type followed by .Type. The metatype of a protocol type—not the
> concrete type that conforms to the protocol at runtime—is the name of
> that protocol followed by .Protocol. For example, the metatype of the
> **class** type `SomeClass` is `SomeClass.Type` and the metatype of the
> **protocol** `SomeProtocol` is `SomeProtocol.Protocol`.

> <sub>From Apple : [metaType Type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/types/#Metatype-Type)</sub>

[Under the hood](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anyclass) `AnyClass` is

```
typealias AnyClass = AnyObject.Type // which is why you see T.Type
```

Basically wherever you see `AnyClass`, `Any.Type`, `AnyObject.Type`, its because it's in need of a type. A very very common place we see it is when we want to *register* a class for our tableView using `register` func.

```
func register(_ cellClass: Swift.AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

<sub>If you are confused as to what does 'Swift.' do then above, then see the comments from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41708033/what-is-swift-anyclass?noredirect=1#comment70613308_41708033)</sub>

The above could have also been written as:

```
func register(_ cellClass: AnyObject.Type, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

## .self

> You can use the *postfix* self expression to access a type as a value.
> For example, SomeClass.self returns SomeClass itself, **not** an instance
> of SomeClass. And SomeProtocol.self returns SomeProtocol itself, **not**
> an instance of a type that conforms to SomeProtocol at runtime. You
> can use a `type(of:)` expression with an instance of a type to access
> that instance’s dynamic, runtime type as a value, as the following
> example shows:

> <sub>From Apple : [metaType Type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/types/#Metatype-Type)</sub>

---

Playground code:

**Easy example**

```
struct Something {
    var x = 5
}

let a = Something()
type(of: a) == Something.self // true
```

**Hard example**

```
class BaseClass {
    class func printClassName() {
        print("BaseClass")
    }
}
class SubClass: BaseClass {
    override class func printClassName() {
        print("SubClass")
    }
}


let someInstance: BaseClass = SubClass()
/*                    |          |
                compile time  runtime
                      |          | 
To extract, use:    .self     type(of)
 
  Check the runtime type of someInstance using `type(of:)`: */

print(type(of: someInstance) == SubClass.self) // True
print(type(of: someInstance) == BaseClass.self) // False

 /* Check the compile time type of someInstance using `is`: */

print(someInstance is SubClass) // True
print(someInstance is BaseClass) // True
```

I highly recommend to read [Apple documentation on Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/types/). Also see [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210924141554/http://en.swifter.tips/self-anyclass/)

Comment: I'm not a strong swift programmer, but I guess `tableView.register(Class, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomTableViewCell")
` is what a novice programmer would try instead of `Class.self` to pass a type into a function? Why is `Class.self` needed when `Class` seems syntactically simpler?

Comment: `Table.Type` is used for when a function expects a type, not an instance. `Table` is used when a function expects an instance of that type. Respectfully `Table.self` and `Table()` satisfy such functions expectations. These 4 distinct purposes hence you can’t do what you say

Comment: I understand why the metatype needs to be used in the function signature, but why does one have to pass as argument, `Table.self`, why not just `Table`, as it seems simpler and can also be possible. I don't see the purpose of the `type as a value` phenomenon.

Comment: Oh, `Table` on its own would just signify a 'return type', rather than be usable as a value, so using `type as a value` **is** important. Thanks

Comment: @BenButterworth my answer to your question is nothing but what I just said. If it helps [newacct's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31441486/5175709) also answers your question. It's merely how the compiler was designed to read

Comment: Yes, my question is about the *mere* compiler design: to rephrase, *why use Class.self* when you can design the compiler to work with `Class`, and my previous comment hopes to answer this. It seems like if swift had a smarter compiler it could be possible to use `Class` in place of `Class.Type` and `Class.self`, and it uses the syntax to determine which what you meant.

Comment: I don't know. You should ask Swift designers

Answer (score 17):

They appear in different places syntactically.

In a place syntactically where you have to specify a type, `Something.Type` is a valid type, corresponding to the type that is the metatype (which is metaclass for classes) of `Something`. `Something.self` is not a valid syntax for a type.

In a place syntactically where you have to write an expression, `Something.self` is a valid expression. It's an expression of type `Something.Type`, and the value is the thing ("class object" in the case of classes) that represents the type `Something`. `Something.Type` is not a valid expression syntax.

Answer (score 3):

This was one of those topics that confused the hell out of me today.

I was writing a generic function:

```
func foo<T: Protocol>(ofType: T.Type) {
    T.bar()
}
```

And tried calling it as follows:

```
foo(ofType: ClassImplementingProtocol.Type) // Compiler error
```

Spent about 30 min researching why it wasn't working. Then I tried this:

```
foo(ofType: ClassImplementingProtocol.self) // Works
```

Turns out Xcode's code completion is very bad at showing the difference between meta types and types... From the code completion pop-up it looks like .self and .Type are the same thing:

[image]

But the "explain like im 5" of it is, when you have a method parameter of Class.Type, it is expecting an instance of Class.Type.

Class.self returns an instance of Class.Type, whereas Class.Type is referring to Class.Type...

Very unclear if you ask me.

Comment: `Class.self` is to `Class.Type` as `"Hello World\n"` is to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

**Metatype <>.Type**

`Metatype` is a type which allows you to **access** to parts of **Class and Struct**[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59219141/4770877) type(not instance) like:

- initializers
- **class and static**[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59236762/4770877) properties and methods

```
//instance.self -> instance
let x1: SomeClass = SomeClass().self
         
//SomeType.self -> SomeType.Type //Metatype
let x2: SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self
         
//SomeType.Type.self -> SomeType.Type //Metatype
let x3: SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self.self
```

```
let var1: String = HelloWorld
let var2: String.Type = HelloWorld.self
```

Some experiments:

```
class SomeClass {
    required init() { }
    
    class func classFunc() { }
    static func staticFunc() { }
    
    func instanceFunc() { }
}

class SubClass: SomeClass { }
```

```
//work with instance
let a1: SomeClass = SomeClass()
let a2: SomeClass = a1
let a3: SomeClass = a1.self

assert(a1 === a2 && a1 === a3)

//static. metatype by Type(class name) <Class_Name>.self <Structure_Name>.self
let c1: SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self
//dynamic. metatype by Instance
let c2: SomeClass.Type = type(of: a1)

assert(c1 == c2)

//access to init
let d0: SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self.self
let d1: SomeClass = d0.init() //SomeClass.Type.self.init
let d2: SomeClass = c1.init()

assert(d1 !== d2)

//call func
SomeClass.classFunc()
c1.classFunc()

SomeClass.staticFunc()
c1.staticFunc()

//        c1.foo3() //Error: Instance member 'foo3' cannot be used on type 'SomeClass'

//work with subclass, class and struct
// <class_name>.Type allows to save class and subclass
var e1: SomeClass.Type = SomeClass.self //class
assert("SomeClass" == "\(e1)")

e1 = SubClass.self //sub class
assert("SubClass" == "\(e1)")

//Any.Type allows to work with class and struct
var e2: Any.Type = SomeClass.self //class
e2 = String.self //struct

//AnyObject.Type allows to work only with class
var e3: AnyObject.Type = SomeClass.self //class
e3 = NSString.self //class

let f1: SomeClass = SubClass()
assert("SubClass" == stringOf(instance: f1))
```

get String

```
let typeString = "\(SomeType.Type)" //"SomeType"

//or

func stringOf<T>(instance: T) -> String {
    let result = String(describing: type(of: instance))
    return result
}

stringOf(instance: SomeType()) //"SomeType"
```