# what's the difference between typing String() and String.self in swift?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm kind of stuck trying to understand `.self` in swift, always I register a custom cell in an collectionView or an tableView I have to register like `customCollectionViewCell.self` but why not for example `customCollectionViewCell()` ?

I've tried in the playground to type `String.self` in a var to see what happens and it give me no errors but when I try to give it a value it give me the following error

> Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type `String.Type`

what does it mean?

Comment: you register the `Class` with .self.  You would be creating an instance with customCollectionViewCell().

Comment: `String.self` refers to the *Type* **String**. `String()` is an *Instance* of the **String** class

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41709040/5175709) and also there is a reason for why we're passing a _Type_ rather than an object itself. You normally pass types to functions where it's not needed for you to instantiate that object yourself rather that function will instantiate the object for you!

Answer (score 5):

`Type()` is shorthand notation for `Type.init()`, so `String()` calls `String.init()` and hence initialises a `String`.

On the other hand, `String.self` returns the meta type of `String`, which is a type that represents the `String` type itself rather than any instance of that type. For more information on meta types, see the [Metatype Type](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#grammar_metatype-type) section of the official Swift language reference.

In your specific example, you need to register a `UITableViewCell` subclass type rather than an instance of a specific type, hence you need to use `YourCellType.self`.

Comment: The answer would be more complete  if you also explain or add a link as to **why** we're passing the _type_ for dequeueing purposes