# Something.self vs self.something in Swift

Tags: swift

I understand that

```
self.something
```

this is member value for that class.
but what is

```
something.self
```

Comment: The syntax is a bit confusing because it originally comes from Objective-C where the `self` property was a property that returned the object itself. Basically, `SomeType.self` is explicitly saying that you want to pass `SomeType` as a parameter.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438368/swift-whats-the-difference-between-metatype-type-and-self/41709040#41709040). Just read til the horizontal line. Beyond that isn't much related to your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider code like

```
JSONDecoder().decode(what, from: myJSONData)
```

What goes where I have `what`? We have to tell the decoder what type of thing to expect to decode. Basically, `what` is the *name of a type* — the name of a class, struct, or enum that conforms to Decodable.

But how to say the name of a type? Let's suppose that the type of thing you expect to decode is String. Then what do you say here?

```
JSONDecoder().decode(String, from: myJSONData) // error
```

No, you can't just say the name of a type out of the blue like that. This is how you do it:

```
JSONDecoder().decode(String.self, from: myJSONData)
```

What you're really passing here when you say `String.self` is the *metatype* for String. And this example is exactly what it's for, i.e. when you need to pass a type as a parameter.

The declaration of this method signals this by using `.Type`:

```
func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, from data: Data) throws -> T where T : Decodable
```

The expression `T.Type` tells you that what you pass when you call this method should be `Something.self`.

Comment: For some context as to why you can't just use `String` like you tried: Using typenames directly to refer to type objects leads to an ambiguity. Example: does `let x = [String]` mean `let x = Array<String>` (a type object), or does it mean `let x = Array(arrayLiteral: String)` (a single-member array containing the `String` type object)

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I'd just say that String plain and simple is the type of an _instance_ to be passed here. When you declare `var s : String` you are saying "give me _a_ String (instance)". So clearly you can't use that same syntax when you want to pass String, _itself_. The `.self` suffix says exactly that!

Comment: "So clearly you can't use that same syntax when you want to pass String, itself. " Nope, there's no reason why that couldn't be the case. You *could* design the language to overload the syntax to have two meanings, like how `()` is both a type and a value.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Now, having said that, do I ever forget to add `.self` when calling `decode()` or implementing `layerClass` or whatever? Yes, all the time. :) So clearly my inner brain agrees with you: it expects that sort of overloading.