# How to get your own app version from xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I wonder if there is a way to get your own app version in code after you put it in the "Summary" tab in xCode. One way seems to be to search `Info.plist` for `CFBundleVersion` key, but is there any other, easier, more convenient way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can my iphone app detect its own version number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458632/how-can-my-iphone-app-detect-its-own-version-number)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can find it in the main bundle. I think it's something like:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Comment: Yeah, I've just found a blog(http://pigtailsoft.com/blog/?p=35) that states that. Thanks anyway! Will accept answer in 6 mins:)

Comment: Thank you, but `@"CFBundleVersion"` return the build not the version. You should get this object: `@"CFBundleShortVersionString"`

Answer (score 28):

I typically use the Build number (`CFBundleVersion`) to keep track of, well, the number of builds, and the Version number (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) for marketing purposes. I use a run script to auto-increment my build number and I update the version number manually before each new release. So if you want to include the actual Version number in your code as opposed to the Build number, use this:

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```

or

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];
```

Here's the run script that increments the build number for anyone interested:

```
#!/bin/bash

buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

Answer (score 15):

For Swift:

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString")
```

Answer (score 12):

```
NSString *version = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```