# Is it possible in iOS to detect if your App was updated?

Tags: ios

Sadly, when my App is updated there is some saved data or left over logic that was already implemented. This can cause some bugs to occur. Is there a way to tell if an App was updated so I can make the user relogin? Any tips or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Check application version - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957794/how-to-get-your-own-app-version-from-xcode

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3015796/how-to-programmatically-display-version-build-number-of-target-in-ios-app

Comment: store app version in NUserDefault for first time afterwords compare with stored value and save again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can save the installed version in the `NSUserDefaults`. They will persist during app updates, so whenever your app launches you check for the saved version, compare it with the current version and do your migration if necessary. At the end, save the new version to the same key.