# Get name of iOS app from path

Tags: iphone, ios, jailbreak

I'm developing an app for jailbroken iOS devices that collects statistics about installed apps (ideally stats about both App Store and Cydia apps). Given the path of an app, is there an easy and reliable way to get the name of the App (as it appears in the Springboard)? Or is there a better way, not using the path at all (ie, is the info centralized somewhere)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a StackOverflow that shows how to get a bundle info plist value (In this case the version).
[How can my iphone app detect its own version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458632/how-can-my-iphone-app-detect-its-own-version-number)

I beleive the attribute you are looking for is CFBundleDisplayName.

Here is apples list of attributes you can obtain.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Strangely enough, there was one app that didn't have the entry `CFBundleDisplayName`, but it does have the app name in `CFBundleExecutable`, perhaps that's an alternative.

Comment: That is interesting.  It is true that even though a Default BUNDLE is put together for you when you initialize your project, you yourself can still delete fields from it.  Perhaps somehow that app developer deleted the CFBundleDisplayName field LOL.  Wierd, but interesting :-)

Answer (score 0):

Every app has an info plist that contains its name and icon. Just look inside the .app bundle.