# How to check new version is available on iTunes?

Tags: iphone, ios, version, itunes

I need to check my iOS app version on iTunes. If a newer version is available, I want to show UIAlert. I don't want to store version number on my server, because a newer version can be available at any time.

Is it possible to check my app version on iTunes?

Comment: If by version you mean an update, this will happen automatically. On user's device they'll get a red badge on their app to notify an update.

Comment: yes, i know it. but some users ignore them. when the my app starts i want to check my apps version on iTunes then compare with running app's. if they are not same i will inform him/her. maybe i will open the appstore.

Comment: Maybe you can try CodaFi's comment on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11288745/876283

Comment: i think i should check the app's website on itunes.apple.com/us/app/**** for string "Version:". then i can read the version number. ok thanks.

Comment: That's a bad idea. Apple provides a JSON API for the iTunes Store. Have a look at the link in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Have a look at this very recommendable open source library for iOS and Mac OS X: https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion