# iOS : how can I check programmatically if the app is up to date?

Tags: ios, version

I want to check if my app is up to date, and if not suggest to download the latest one.

I went through [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458632/how-can-my-iphone-app-detect-its-own-version-number) and found some ideas, but I still don't know how to check the latest version.

I also would like to know how I can display this information only one time and not every time the user launches the app or the main view appears.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288745/ios-app-update-notification

Answer (score 4):

This control: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/harpy does it for you. Just need to integrate it...