# IOS app update check within application

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

I need to check application updation in apple store within the application.
Every time application starting we need to check this..

please check answer in below post:
[iOS app update notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11288745/ios-app-update-notification)

which one is best option? Harpy or any other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a WebService on your server (or something similar) that your app requests at startup, to know which is the latest version available. (If you don't have a WS yet and really don't want to implement one for that, you may also simply use an XML or text file that contains the version too)

Then compare this version retrieved from your server with the current version of the application, using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"].`

If they are different, you can display the alertview and redirect to itms-`apps://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=[APPID]&mt=8` (replacing APPID with your iTunes Connect App ID), which is the link that will make your iPhone open the AppStore application directly on your application's update page.

You can go with [this](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy/tree/master/Harpy) too but if you Scrape from the app store you're always at risk of having the app store updated and your apps won't be able to fetch the latest version, so you must go with your own version checks like upper steps.

Comment: I would go with this as the correct answer, you need to depend on your own service to get the value of latest version, if you Scrape the app store you're always at risk of having the app store updated and your apps won't be able to fetch the latest version, so you must go with your own version checks like @Rajneesh071 did.

Comment: which one is better? 1) our server application will handle the version detail, every time we need to check with that and give alert to user  2) use https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy/tree/master/Harpy this

Comment: Maybe, with upcoming iOS7 this kind of things doesn't needed anymore. iOS will do automatic update of application.

Comment: with present ios you also dont need to check .. just open itune and it  will show that which application have new version

Comment: This isn't true. Users can still turn off the auto-update feature in the Settings app.