# How to get notified when my app becomes available on the Apple Store

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Is there some mechanism (like a web hook or an endpoint that I can poll) to know when my app becomes available on the Apple store?

I want to use this to trigger some other processes.

I have seen the iTunes api [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32835100/7274936), and I assume I can setup a script to poll this endpoint every hour or something for different regions that my app is available in, and I have also seen that the App store connect has an API, but I'm not sure if this will give me what I need.

Any ideas? Preferably a Web hook.

Answer (score 0):

There is no official webhook from Apple. So the solution would properly be to use one of the methods you already linked to.

When that is said. I have created my own webhook, so I don't need to have a script polling on Apple's servers all the time.

When the state of your app change, Apple is sending out an email with the new state.
I forward the email to an Email Worker on [Cloudflare](https://developers.cloudflare.com/email-routing/email-workers/).
This will look at the subject to determine what the new state is.
Depending on the state I then either call my own API to run some other processes or sending a message to Slack.

I have been using it for some time now and it's a really cool solution

Answer (score 0):

Like previously answered, there's no official webhook for this. But just like Dinsen, I too created my own solution for this problem by using the App Store Connect API and monitoring for changes. For now it just sends a notification to Slack, but a webhook wouldn't be a bad idea to add.

If you'd like to try this solution of mine, there's a free trial: https://statused.com

Happy to help if you have any other questions