# Remove feature in submitted App

Tags: iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I currently have an App on the App Store with features `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`

I am looking to make features `c` and `d` paid for using in-app purchasing in the future but until that is all programmed/implemented; also restrict or remove (visible) access to those features. Note anyone that had previously setup `c` or `d` will maintain access to them.

Is it ok to remove features like that in a submitted application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use your applicaion's version for that purpose.

Three steps to follow:

1. Detect the app's first launch [Link for first time app launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964371/how-to-detect-first-time-app-launch-iphone)
2. and at that moment you save your version number  [Link to get app's version number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458632/how-can-my-iphone-app-detect-its-own-version-number)
3. once you intend to display a feature do something like

   ```
   NSString *currentVersion = @"1.2.0";
   NSString *versionAtAppDownload = @"1.1.5";
   if ([currentVersion compare:versionAtAppDownload options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending) {

      //decide what to do
   }
   ```

This should be added in your next app version. Once done, everybody who already downloaded your app should have saved their current app version.

Now your update to your next bigger version i.e. `1.2.0`, this version will be the one that hides content for users that have not yet paid. The users who downloaded your app at any previous version should be able to still see everything.

Something like this should work, good luck!

Comment: and... what if the customer will delete the app from device ... and after a while... it will try to install again? Answer: the customer will remain without the removed feature :)

Comment: once you deleted the app, all app relevant data on the device gets lost. So in order to avoid this, you will need to have your own server that stores the users who already downloaded your app. This can be done by registrating the user for example via email or you use iCloud or something similar.

Comment: not all the customers will see the developer's announce with register to "keep the features"... will be always some "collateral damage"... :)

Comment: yes that is true. you probably should wait one or two month with publishing your new version then. Or you find a better solution. If so I would be highly interested in how you solved this problem :)