# How to get application version using libgdx/robovm

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx, robovm

I have some questions about getting the version of application developed on top of libgdx (and also on robovm for ios)

I want to get the version information

1. That is declared in `android:versionName` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` for Android
2. That is declared in `app.version` key of `robovm.properties` for IOS. (Which, I believe, is eventually replaced for value of `CFBundleShortVersionString` key in `Info.plist.xml`)

My first question is, does libgdx provide a platform independent method for getting app version? (I could not find any)

If not I found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application) to get app version on android, that's OK. Found [same answer for IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/458632/how-can-my-iphone-app-detect-its-own-version-number) but in a native way. How can I do same thing using robovm backend?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think libgdx provides a platform independent way to do this. Here's how to get the `CFBundleShortVersionString` value for your app using RoboVM's CocoaTouch bindings:

```
NSDictionary infoDictionary = NSBundle.getMainBundle().getInfoDictionary();
String version = infoDictionary.get(new NSString("CFBundleShortVersionString")).toString();
```

You can use the same method to get `CFBundleVersion` etc from your app's Info.plist file.