# Access Device and OS information in a Kotlin Multiplatform mobile Project

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am working on a Kotlin Multiplatform Project and I need to access following device data

- appVersion
- connection type: Wifi or cellular
- Carrier
- Os version
- Device model

How can I access following data from an iOS as well as Android device in a kotlin multiplatform project?

Can I access them in iOS main and Android main or do I need to pass some reference?

Answer (score 3):

One of the Kotlin Multiplatform's core features is an ability to utilize platform-specific APIs. See an explanation and examples [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mobile/connect-to-platform-specific-apis.html).
I would recommend you to go through the Web and search for a way people get this data on Android or iOS natively, and then re-implement those approaches in your project - Android main contents won't take a lot of time to be adjusted. iOS one might be a little more complicated, but all Apple's frameworks should be accessible as `platform.<FrameworkName>` and their usage won't be too different from Objective-C's one.
For the app version, to begin with, I think those pieces of advice would be good examples: [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11964018/11533773) & [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4929559/11533773).