# iPhone: Updated version doesn't update application binary?

Tags: iphone, app-store

I have couple of applications alive in Apple store and we have just released updated version of these applications with incremented version numbers. I found that all resources are getting updated correctly(updated splash screen, background image etc) but newly added features are not getting updated. For example, I have included a feature so that iPhone app takes new contents from my website. It doesn't happen when I update the application from Appstore updates list.

...but the other strange thing is if I delete the application from my iPhone and download it again from Apple store then everything works fine!! I am not able to understand what has been going on. Anyone could please help me to debug this?

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311405/iphone-update-application-version-in-settings) I got following code and added in my AppDelegate. For me it always print Version (null). I could see version number correctly set in my Application-info.plist file though!

```
#if DDEBUG // debugging/testing
NSString *versionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];
#else
NSString *versionString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]];
#endif // DDEBUG
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:versionString forKey:@"version"];
printf("Version: = %s\n", [versionString cStringUsingEncoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding]);
[defaults synchronize]; // force immediate saving of defaults.
```

Following code works though! I mean it prints the correct version available in application-info.plist file! Got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/877128/how-can-i-display-the-application-version-revision-in-my-applications-settings-b)

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"Version: %@", version);
[defaults setObject:version forKey:@"version_preference"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I can confirm if this fixes the issue after resubmitting the application.

Thanks.

Comment: It may be possible that the binary you had on device was the one you had downloaded from xcode and not downloaded from app-store.

Comment: nope...its been happening on users phone where I don't run xcode at all!

Comment: Hi Praveen, do you think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311405/iphone-update-application-version-in-settings might be an issue? We update version number in application setting plist file.

Comment: AppleDeveloper Can you print the values and check. I have updated 4 of my apps 6 times and never faced such issue. Usually a update is new download with retaining the user details.

Comment: Hi Praveen, please see edited question. Not sure what's going on! It always prints Version (null) for me! Moreover, what is Root.plist? I don't have it my application!

Comment: You need to set the plist file name in your application settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"Version: %@", version);
[defaults setObject:version forKey:@"version_preference"];
[defaults synchronize];
```