# Difference between Xcode version (CFBundleShortVersionString) and build (CFBundleVersion)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

[image: App Target Summary]

In Xcode 4, I see this for my target summary:

The "Version" input corresponds to `CFBundleShortVersionString` in the info.plist file, and the "Build" input corresponds to `CFBundleVersion`.

What's the difference between these two? I see a lot of people on the internet wanting to put the same value in for both, and my suspicion is that is for backwards compatability.

I have two questions:

1) If I were starting from scratch, what would be the best practice for versioning your app?

2) In all previous releases of my app, I only used `CFBundleVersion`. In order to not mess up the upgrade process, should I continue to increment `CFBundleVersion` the same way I have been or is it possible to switch to the "right way", assuming one exists?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851660/version-vs-build-in-xcode-4 but perhaps this version is better stated (and has a screenshot).

Comment: Is there anything you had to do to show the Build field in your Summary? I only see a Version, but no Build field.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The Apple document ["Information Property List Key Reference"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009249-102364-TPXREF106) says that `CFBundleShortVersionString` represents a release version, whereas `CFBundleVersion` represents any build, released or not.  Also, `CFBundleShortVersionString` can be localized, though I don't know why you'd want to, since they say it is supposed to be "a string comprised of three period-separated integers".  For a release build, it would be reasonable to make the two numbers the same.  For a development build, you might tack something else on to the `CFBundleVersion`, maybe another dot and integer.

Comment: But if I've currently been using 1.3.1 as my `CFBundleVersion` and nothing as my `CFBundleShortVersionString`, and I want to switch to using `CFBundleVersion` to represent internal builds, then I *need* to at least start with an integer higher than 1.3.1, right? Or is making that switch just asking for trouble?

Comment: The Version (`CFBundleShortVersionString`) is the only thing that will matter for submitting to Apple. The Build (`CFBundleVersion`) is for use however you like in development, or to show within your app. Use octal (base-8) and iterate in reverse by 12, if you like.

Comment: nekno: Actually the CFBundleVersion is what matters to Apple. Check this error message Apple give when submitting an app: "The binary you uploaded was invalid. The key CFBundleVersion in the Info.plist file must contain a higher version than that of the previously uploaded version."

Comment: Some countries use numerals other that Modern Arabic used in western world, like Eastern Arabic (٠‎, ١‎, ٢‎, ٣‎, ٤‎, ٥‎, ٦‎, ٧‎, ٨‎, ٩‎), or Hebrew (א ,ב, ג, ד, ה, ו, ז, ח, ט) - and those two are also written right to left. There are many more other numeral systems out there (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Numerals) So my guess is that's what Apple means by "localizable" version number.

Comment: By the way, the three digits with punctuation is not required. I have been using instead a date-time value such as `201606070620` for both values in a shipping iOS 7-8-9 app.

Comment: And the version number can be followed with a "alpha" or "beta".
The 3 integers are not the final solution to versioning and luckily the syntax is not enforced by apple (but the CFBundleVersion  is)

Comment: Apple's tech note [TN2420](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2420/_index.html) clarifies how the `CFBundleVersion` and `CFBundleShortVersionString` actually work in practise, confirming Xcode (9)'s labelling of `CFBundleVersion` simply as a build number.

Answer (score 3):

To JWWalker's question on why you would want to localize CFBundleShortVersionString, that would be the decimal separator. For example in locales where the decimal separator is actually a comma, the version "1.5" would be "1,5".

Comment: IMO you don't need to localize version numbers. I live in a region where the decimal separator is a comma (Germany), and I'm used to version numbers separated by a dot. In fact, I can't remember that I ever saw a version number with a comma.

Comment: I also live in a region using comma as decimal separator, though 1,3,1 is quite a odd value, 1.3.1 seems much better.

Comment: I think it means that you can have different versions of the app for different regions. 

1.2.1 > en.lproj
1.2.2 > fr.lproj

Though the whole plist is copied when you localize the file so both version numbers copied in so both 'can be localized'

Answer (score 1):

Quick Fix:

Just add the `CFBundleShortVersionString` to the plist file and edit your version.

1. Reveal your `InfoPlist.strings`
2. Highlight it and paste the code below in (assuming its in source code mode)

> {"CFBundleShortVersionString" = "1.1";}

3. Change the 1.1 to whatever your new build is.
4. Build & submit with no more error!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the Apple documentation on uploading binaries.

> Numbering versions and builds: 
>   iTunes Connect extracts its prerelease version number and build number
>   from the binary. The prerelease version number is the Xcode Version
>   number, or the "Bundle version string, short" key in the Info.plist.
>   The build number is the Xcode Build number, or the "Bundle version"
>   key in the Info.plist. The prerelease version number and build number
>   will be shown on the Prerelease tab, as described in Viewing Builds.

[Uploading a Binary For An App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/UploadingBinariesforanApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH38-SW1)