# krooshal.com + build.phonegap.com = no Info.plist

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

When I try to upload an app to [Krooshal](https://www.krooshal.com/) from Adobe "[build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com)", not a Phonegap app, but one from their build service. I get this error when creating a new app in Krooshal:

`Unable to find Info.plist`

I assume that the Adobe build service does not include this file, since I am not an objective c developer, I am not sure what this files does or if there a way I can manually include it in my **WWW** folder before I send to the build service.

Thanks in advance for any help!

~Red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the plist generated by build.phonegap.com, it appears that CFBundleShortVersionString is not populated, CFBundleVersion is. [CFBundleShortVersionString represents release, whereas CFBundleVersion represents any build](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6881469/1480400). [Krooshal](https://www.krooshal.com) supports both attributes now.

Comment: Thanks again for the fast response & fix!