# invalid binary because of CFBundleVersion .iTunesConnect is Rejecting

Tags: ios, cordova

[image]I am facing following issue.

Version Mismatch - Neither CFBundleVersion ['1.50'] nor CFBundleShortVersionString ['1.30'] in the Info.plist match the version of the app set in iTunes Connect ['RTT1.92.196'].

My old version is 1.2(CFBundleVersion). The application is validating successfully in Xcode,but after submitting in iTunesConnect.com , i am getting above error.

i Changed it to (CFBundleVersion)2.1,1.4.1,2.3,2,2.1...etc But they are rejecting. I checked in info.plist file there are no duplicate tags for CFBundleVersion,even i deleted archive files also.

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: you tried my solution?

Comment: Hi i tried your solution. But again rejected.In itunes connect my old version it showing that 1.1

Comment: Please see my updated question. One image is attached.

Answer (score 2):

There are two strings in the Info.plist file that you will want to check. CFBundleShortVersionString and CFBundleVersion. The second is the important one that you want to match what you have on iTunesConnect.

Also, remember that when parsing the parts of the version, Apple strips zeros so version 1.02 becomes version 1.2 to them.

There's more on the CFBundle info here: [Difference between Xcode version (CFBundleShortVersionString) and build (CFBundleVersion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876923/difference-between-xcode-version-cfbundleshortversionstring-and-build-cfbundl)

Comment: @Aaron Bratcher: Because the `CFBundleShortVersionString` is the release version, shouldn't that version match to the version set in iTunes Connect?