# Post script target build phase in Xcode how to embed a build version?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, iphone

In Xcode, I've added a script target build phase so I can run an arbitrary script upon a successful build of my project. Where I'm stuck is, I'm trying to get the version of our build passed into the script by any means.. it looks like the only way is to parse Settings.app/Root.plist and retrieve a hard coded build version that I have embedded in there. Is there any other way to go about this in a way that makes sense? I'm open for using any scripting environment, particularly Python since if I have to end up doing XML parsing, it's straight forward doing it there.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to include a Subversion build number into your project, something like [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372218/insert-subversion-revision-number-in-xcode/414792#414792) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372218/insert-subversion-revision-number-in-xcode) might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by moving the build action to first in the series of actions. Feel free to read about it [here](http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/10/17/AdHoc-changes.html).

I just added the time for the "extra" number added to "1.0". Think you should easily be able to insert your `svn` command.

The plist must also be converted binary back and forth.

Then you should be able to get this version string from the app itself when running with this

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSDictionary *info = [bundle infoDictionary];
    NSString *prodName = [info objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```