# What's the best way to get an auto-incremental build number for a php web application?

Tags: php, svn, auto-increment

I want to put an auto-incremental build number in my PHP-based web application.

Since I'm not compiling, but I'm using svn for source control, I thought that maybe each checkout could count as a build.

Am I right?

If so, how can I get the current svn revision number **of the production server local copy** via PHP?

If not, what would you say is the best method to put an auto-incremental build number in a web app?

Answer (score 2):

Not used SVN for a long time, but this should work.

```
$var = '$Id:$';
```

SVN replaces `$Id:$` on every checkout

Update: Seems, that `$Rev:$` is more convenient.

Comment: Thanks! Tried this and it works great! But only if the current file has changed :S

Answer (score 0):

I think [Getting the last revision number in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579196/getting-the-last-revision-number-in-svn) might answer your question!

Answer (score 0):

I found this [How can I get the svn revision number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111436/how-can-i-get-the-svn-revision-number-in-php)

Where somebody says that on the deployment script you can include:

```
cd /var/www/project
svn update
rm version.php
svnversion > version.php
```

To fill version.php with the current svn version.

Then, you include version.php where you need it.

Also, I found this, that seems to work without updating a specific file:

```
$path='path_to_your_project';
function get_svn_revision ($path)
{
    $cmd = 'svnversion -n ' . $path;
    $result = (int)exec ($cmd);
    return $result;
}
```

But since I didn't want to execute a command, I ended up querying /.svn/entries at the root of the project using:

```
$path='path_to_your_project';
function get_svn_revision($path) {
    $svn = File($path . '/.svn/entries');
    //Revision number is the fourth line
    $result = $svn[3];
    unset($svn);
    return $result;
}
```