# Get SVN revision number into NSIS script

Tags: svn, nsis

I'd like to capture the svn revision of my code automatically when I build an installer using NSIS.  I see I can get the revision number by calling "svnversion" at the command line, but how can I map that to a `${define}` in my NSIS script at build time?

Comment: What are you using to build? nant? msbuild? scons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute any command at compile time with [!system](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.1.12) and then get/parse the output with [!searchparse](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter5.html#5.4.13), `!define /file` or `!include`.

Another alternative is the `$Revision$` [svn keyword](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111436/how-can-i-get-the-svn-revision-number-in-php) for more)

Comment: Thanks Anders, I got it working with this:
`!tempfile "svnrev.txt"
!appendfile "svnrev.txt" "!define SVN_REV "
!system "svnversion ..\ >> svnrev.txt"
!include "svnrev.txt"
!delfile "svnrev.txt"
 
DetailPrint ${SVN_REV}`

Answer (score 0):

If you use Windows (you use it, isn't it?), you can use SubWCRev from TortoiseSVN.

I.e:

- you have *template* of NSIS script, in which repository-related data is replaced by SubWCRev-keywords
- Your build-system use SubWCRev at some stage in order to get actual script, with up-to-date data from repo

Example (extraction from my template in project)

```
// (C) 2009-$WCDATE=%Y$
// Assembled from $WCDATE=%Y%m%d$-r$WCREV$
```

will appear in final file after SubWCRev magic as (for last build)

```
// (C) 2009-2012
// Assembled from 20120122-r1143
```

New revision - new data, updated header