# why can't windows based php exec() run svn command with url defined?

Tags: php, svn

I have a php script which i use to pull the svn version number (fyi: accepted answer here: [How can I get the svn revision number in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111436/how-can-i-get-the-svn-revision-number-in-php) is incorrect).

i first run:

```
exec('svn info | grep URL', $y);
```

to get the url of the repo, and then run:

```
exec('svn info ' . $url . ' | grep Revision', $z);
```

to get the revision of the latest in repo.

the first command runs fine; but the 2nd hangs in Windows. I am pretty sure this used to work; any ideas why adding the url to the svn command fails in Windows PHP exec call?

Comment: Did you urlencode the url or just leave spaces in it?

Comment: did not urlencode; but no spaces in the url to worry about.

Comment: also, command line svn does not recognize urlencoded urls