# SVN revision number as on Stackoverflow site (right bottom)

Tags: svn

How do I get my SVN revision number to appear on my website each time I commit?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163/how-do-i-sync-the-svn-revision-number-with-my-asp-net-web-site

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/how-to-access-the-current-subversion-build-number

Answer (score 3):

You must have something like `$Revision$` in the file whose revision you want to track (say `foo.html`), and tell Svn to track and substitute that keyword in the file, i.e.:

```
svn propset svn:keywords "Revision" foo.html
```

Svn will then, when the file's changed, change that expression into `$Revision: 23` or whatever the revision number may be.  (You can do that in other files too, of course, but then -- depending how you compose your site -- you'll have to get the info from each file of interest and add it to the page you're displaying, e.g. via templating or whatever).

Comment: It is worth emphasising that using `$Revision$` in a single file will *not* automatically update its value when changes are made to other files.

Comment: Think it's not emphasized enough in my answer?  I have it in the very first line and again in the parentheses at the end...

Comment: I just often see this problem as a "Frequently Encountered Unexpected Result", so perhaps stating it in black and white *is* necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like they embed it in the page ("view source" on this page):

```
<div id="svnrev">svn revision: 4999</div>
```

I can get it using Tortoise on Windows by looking at the log for a repository.  You don't say what OS you're using or if it's command shell access for you.

Check the [SVN Red Bean book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn-book.html) for the command you need.

Comment: They use C#, so probably some variable in a global class.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you will need to execute `svn info` on command line and then parse the output (so given this happens on the server). See this [blog entry](http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/23/automatic-build-sub-versioning-in-xcode) for example

The output from svn info looks like this:

```
Path: .
URL: http://continuum.td.foo.com/svn/EngTools/Atom/trunk/aimv-test-daemon
Repository Root: http://continuum.td.foo.com/svn
Repository UUID: 69079f5b-ed1a-0410-902f-f9949c1bbd36
Revision: 107090
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: johndoe
Last Changed Rev: 107006
Last Changed Date: 2009-07-09 15:21:17 -0700 (Thu, 09 Jul 2009)
```

Say you don't want to run daemon or exec you can simply dump the content to some known file after you update your build `svn info > svnbuild.info` and parse that

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PHP here, but you could easily do this in any server-side language.

```
<?PHP
$revString = '$Revision$'; // Subversion will substitute something like $Revision: <number> $
$revNum = magic($revString); // magic parses the integer number out of the string.
echo "Subversion revision: $revNum";
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java and Ant, you can use a task to query the repository and store the infos into some Ant properties.  This could be handy to get not only the revision number but also the tag/branch name.

You can see a [sample task in my sandbox](http://code.google.com/p/workingonit/source/browse/trunk/addenda/src/java/org/workingonit/addenda/subversion/SubversionInfoTask.java)