# Getting SVN revision for my ASP .NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, svn, versioning

I need to get the SVN revision for my application versioning (little numbers in the footer).

I have followed this [tutorial](https://versioning.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Instructions&referringTitle=Home) (which I successfully configured in another ASP .NET MVC 2 a couple of years ago) step by step, but I can't make it work.

When trying to compile, I'm getting these errors:

```
MyApp.csproj(141,5): error: Subversion command "svn.exe info -R" exited with code 1
MyApp.csproj(1041,5): error: svn: '.' is not a working copy
MyApp.csproj(1041,5): error:
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I sync the SVN revision number with my ASP.NET web site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163/how-do-i-sync-the-svn-revision-number-with-my-asp-net-web-site)

Comment: is different, I don't want to use cruise control

Comment: Not all of those answers use cruise control, at least one of them uses Subversion properties to fill in the revision information - [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) and the [answer that mentions it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/166/1441)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found the problem.

When executing svn.exe --version I was getting 1.6.17 on the PowerShell. However, when I checked the Tortoise About section the version was using subversion 1.7.5.

I uninstalled the 1.6.17 and everything seems to be working again with the [tutorial](https://versioning.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Instructions&referringTitle=Home) mentioned above.